# Is it possible to transform to lowercase using Eclipse's regex search and replace?

Tags: regex, eclipse

I've tried '\L' but it doesn't seem to be part of its grammar, and its help makes no mention of any available transforms.

I'm aware that I can and know how to do this from the command line but...

Is it possible to do case transforms using Eclipse's regex search and replace?

Comment: You can write a pretty simple plugin to do this, but I don't think search/replace can.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hmm, I don't think it is possible. \L and even \u seem not to work as I expected (at least in Indigo). Maybe it would be better to do that outside of eclipse and then refresh de workspace.

PS: If you feel bored you can search for them and user CTRL+SHIFT+Y and CTRL+SHIFT+X to change the case :P

Answer (score 48):

You can do it in two steps. First you insert the alphabet in lowercase. Then you only keep the right letter:

reg expr 1: `([A-Z])`

replacement 1: `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$1`

reg expr 2: `(a)bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzA|a(b)cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzB|ab(c)defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzC|abc(d)efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzD|abcd(e)fghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzE|abcde(f)ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzF|abcdef(g)hijklmnopqrstuvwxyzG|abcdefg(h)ijklmnopqrstuvwxyzH|abcdefgh(i)jklmnopqrstuvwxyzI|abcdefghi(j)klmnopqrstuvwxyzJ|abcdefghij(k)lmnopqrstuvwxyzK|abcdefghijk(l)mnopqrstuvwxyzL|abcdefghijkl(m)nopqrstuvwxyzM|abcdefghijklm(n)opqrstuvwxyzN|abcdefghijklmn(o)pqrstuvwxyzO|abcdefghijklmno(p)qrstuvwxyzP|abcdefghijklmnop(q)rstuvwxyzQ|abcdefghijklmnopq(r)stuvwxyzR|abcdefghijklmnopqr(s)tuvwxyzS|abcdefghijklmnopqrs(t)uvwxyzT|abcdefghijklmnopqrst(u)vwxyzU|abcdefghijklmnopqrstu(v)wxyzV|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv(w)xyzW|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw(x)yzX|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx(y)zY|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy(z)Z`

replacement 2: `$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10$11$12$13$14$15$16$17$18$19$20$21$22$23$24$25$26`

And you can transform to UPPERCASE like this:

reg expr 1: `([a-z])`

replacement 1: `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ$1`

reg expr 2: `(A)BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZa|A(B)CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZb|AB(C)DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZc|ABC(D)EFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZd|ABCD(E)FGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZe|ABCDE(F)GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZf|ABCDEF(G)HIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZg|ABCDEFG(H)IJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZh|ABCDEFGH(I)JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZi|ABCDEFGHI(J)KLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZj|ABCDEFGHIJ(K)LMNOPQRSTUVWXYZk|ABCDEFGHIJK(L)MNOPQRSTUVWXYZl|ABCDEFGHIJKL(M)NOPQRSTUVWXYZm|ABCDEFGHIJKLM(N)OPQRSTUVWXYZn|ABCDEFGHIJKLMN(O)PQRSTUVWXYZo|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO(P)QRSTUVWXYZp|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP(Q)RSTUVWXYZq|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ(R)STUVWXYZr|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR(S)TUVWXYZs|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS(T)UVWXYZt|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST(U)VWXYZu|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU(V)WXYZv|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV(W)XYZw|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW(X)YZx|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX(Y)Zy|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY(Z)z`

replacement 2: `$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10$11$12$13$14$15$16$17$18$19$20$21$22$23$24$25$26`

Comment: Well, it *is* a solution... : )

Comment: Tested it on 132 matches across 40 files... Worked. That's pretty creative. +1

Comment: 2k17 here : eclipse still can't do the job... but THIS trick still does ! :D

Comment: The old intermediate-universal-Turing-machine-in-regex solution. Awesome.