# Changing case of a letter with regex

Tags: regex, eclipse

I am using regular expressions in Eclipse IDE. I am trying to turn

`other.test` into  `other.getTest()`

Search: `other.([a-z])([a-z]*)`

Replace: `other.\U$1$2()`

Result: `other.Utest()`

I thought that adding a \U in front of the group was supposed to change the case, but its not working for me. any ideas?

Comment: You should use Refactor for that, it will automatically update all references. (doubleclick on test, so it is selected, right click on it, Refactor => Rename... enter otherTest)

Comment: And you need to escape the . (dot)

Comment: Don't think that will work for my needs.  I need to do many fields at once and the changes are only going to be localized to specific methods.  basically trying to change the output of the `equals()` generation to getters instead of direct fields access.  Eclipse does not provide any way to override that.

Comment: where did you find the \U?  I do not think there is an option for upper case with eclipse regex.

Comment: the \U I just got from standard regular expression specs.  I assumed eclipse followed the standards unless they use their own thing?

Comment: This is how you do it in eclipse (2nd answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181107/is-it-possible-to-transform-to-lowercase-using-eclipses-regex-search-and-replac

have fun :)

Comment: wtf..rather just keep doing it manually lol.  anyways. the $ is needed to specify the group, otherwise it just prints a 1

Comment: The \U or the \L replaces the $ as I understood it: $1 => \U1 or \L1 for upper and lower case. Anyways I guess it's just not working in eclipse, but you might consider to write a program, shouldn't take too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Eclipse Find/Replace regex does not support case modifying operators like `\U`, `\u`, `\L` and `\l`. You may either use a long workaround suggested by jrahhali, or use Notepad++:

*Search*: `other\.([a-z]+)`
*Replace*: `other.get\u$1\(\)`

**Explantion**:

- `other\.` - matches a string `other.` (note the dot must be escaped to match a literal dot)
- `([a-z]+)` - Group 1 capturing 1 or more lowercase ASCII letters (check *Match case* option to only match lowercase ASCII letters with `[a-z]+`)

**Replacement pattern details**:

- `other.get` - a literal text `other.get`
- `\u$1` - the contents of Group 1 (the `$1` is a backreference to the captured group 1) and its first character is turned to upper case with `\u` operator (`\U` would turn the whole text of the capture group to upper case)
- `\(\)` - a literal text `()` (the parentheses should be escaped in NPP Boost conditional replacement patterns).

Demo screen:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This works.  You need two passes with search and replace.  Reference from this answer: [Is it possible to transform to lowercase using Eclipse's regex search and replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181107/is-it-possible-to-transform-to-lowercase-using-eclipses-regex-search-and-replac)

```
search 1:  other\.([a-z])([a-z]*)
replace 1: other.ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ$1$2

search 2:  other\.(A)BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZa|A(B)CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZb|AB(C)DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZc|ABC(D)EFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZd|ABCD(E)FGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZe|ABCDE(F)GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZf|ABCDEF(G)HIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZg|ABCDEFG(H)IJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZh|ABCDEFGH(I)JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZi|ABCDEFGHI(J)KLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZj|ABCDEFGHIJ(K)LMNOPQRSTUVWXYZk|ABCDEFGHIJK(L)MNOPQRSTUVWXYZl|ABCDEFGHIJKL(M)NOPQRSTUVWXYZm|ABCDEFGHIJKLM(N)OPQRSTUVWXYZn|ABCDEFGHIJKLMN(O)PQRSTUVWXYZo|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO(P)QRSTUVWXYZp|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP(Q)RSTUVWXYZq|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ(R)STUVWXYZr|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR(S)TUVWXYZs|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS(T)UVWXYZt|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST(U)VWXYZu|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU(V)WXYZv|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV(W)XYZw|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW(X)YZx|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX(Y)Zy|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY(Z)z([a-z]*)
replace 2: other.get$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10$11$12$13$14$15$16$17$18$19$20$21$22$23$24$25$26$27
```

Comment: Actually, this solution effectively works with eclipse. You do not need a workaround. And because it mades a good use of eclipse limited regexp search&replace features, it should be voted as the right answer !

Answer (score -2):

simple one.. according to http://www.regexe.com/ it works fine:

```
search pattern -  other\.t(est)
replace pattern -  other\.getTest\(\)
```

Good luck..

Comment: the solution needs to be more universal that can apply to any `other.xxxx` to `other.getXxxxx()`

Comment: may be this will work -

    search pattern - other\.([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z]*)
    replace pattern - other.get\U$1\E$2