# Change case in search/replace dialog box across entire project

Tags: regex, netbeans, netbeans-12

**The above solution solves the problem. Neither Eclipse nor NetBeans handle `\l`**

**Warning: this is a NetBeans specific question, not a general regular expression question. The problem only occurs in NetBeans' implementation of regular expressions.**

I am trying to change the case of some text across an entire project using NetBeans 12.

In the "Replace in Projects" dialog box, I use a regular expression in the "Containing Text" to find the text:

```
return "([A-Za-z]*)"
```

According to regular expression documentation, if I set the "Replace With" text to

```
\l$1
```

it will change the case of the first letter of the replacement to lower case.

All I get is the letter `l` before the matched string when I complete the replacement.

How do I get the normal `\l` for regular expressions to work in the search/replace dialog of NetBeans 12 without writing any additional Java code?

Comment: ```A-Z``` presents the same problem. I am not having trouble matching, capturing, or retrieving the captured string. The only issue is that ```\l``` it not being recognized as a regular expression command to change the case.

Comment: ```\L``` presents the same problem. Thanks for the link. The problem only occurs in NetBeans regular expressions. I am able to successfully change the case in other versions of regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am sorry if I was not specific enough in the question to identify that this is a NetBeans specific problem. As far as I know, the problem only occurs in NetBeans. It seems to be a NetBeans implementation problem. I saw a post from a long time ago for an earlier version of NetBeans that had the same problem, but a solution was not suggested. The only way to reproduce the problem will be to use NetBeans, use CTRL-H to open the "Replace in Projects" dialog and enter the strings.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31062839/3832970)

Answer (score 2):

RTFM. I went back and read the NetBeans regular expression description, ALL THE WAY TO THE END!

```
The Pattern engine performs traditional NFA-based matching with ordered alternation as occurs in Perl 5.

Perl constructs not supported by this class:

 - The preprocessing operations \l \u, \L, and \U.
```

Instead of deleting the question, I will leave it for anyone else who can't read the documentation.